# How to arrange array to make sections of contacts according to first letter of contact name in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to fetch contacts from device. How to arrange array to make sections of contacts according to first letter of contact name in swift 3?

```
lazy var contacts: [CNContact] = {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let keysToFetch = [
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
            CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
            CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
            CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [Any]

        // Get all the containers
        var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
        do {
            allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching containers")
        }        
        var results: [CNContact] = []        
        // Iterate all containers and append their contacts to our results array
        for container in allContainers {
            let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

            do {
                let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])

                results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching results for container")
            }
        }
        results.sort{$0.givenName < $1.givenName} // sorting array by name
        return results
    }()
```

Answer (score 1):

try creating an array of [String:[CNContact]]
now run your [CNContact] through a loop and app them

```
let sortedContacts = [String:[CNContact]]()
for contact in contacts {
let contactPrefix = contactName(//get contact name and first character)
sortedContacts[contactPrefix].append(contact)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create an array of CNContact arrays.

Comment: Yes this is already array of CNContact but how to arrange it.

Comment: What I meant is that array of CNContact arrays. [[CNContact]].